# Error message using sDNA Integral Analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, sdna

I'm analyzing a road network using the sDNA integral tool, and am getting the following error message. I'm using arcMAP 10.5.

```
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\bin\\sdnaintegral.py", line 4, in <module>
ERR:     commandline_integral_prepare("sdnaintegral")
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\commandline_integral_prepare.py", line 103, in commandline_integral_prepare
ERR:     dll = options.dll)
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\runcalculation.py", line 115, in runcalculation
ERR:     for fid,points,fielddata in env.ReadFeatures(input_handle,names_to_load+text_names_to_load):
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\sdna_environment.py", line 524, in ReadFeatures
ERR:     if(shape.partCount != 1):
ERR: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'partCount'
External command completed
Process did not complete successfully
Completed script sDNAIntegral...
Failed to execute (sDNAIntegral).
Failed at Tue Jul 25 00:50:40 2017 (Elapsed Time: 1 minutes 15 seconds)
```

Comment: It seems to be a DLL rather than Python problem so I think you should check whether you are using a version of sDNA that supports ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.

Comment: I ran the analysis before using the same versions of ArcGIS and sDNA about a month ago, and it was fine, unless one of them updated without my knowledge- could it be something about the format of the road centerline data? I've tried both shp file and file geodatabase feature class..

Comment: Can you re-run the analysis that worked to see if it still does?

Comment: I did and it doesn't work. However, it seems to be working when I take the output of the last run and re-run it through the Integral tool.

Comment: When you tried on shapefile was the output set to a shapefile or was it a gdb feature class?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `shape` is `None`, and reading the source file (`sdna_environment.py`) where the error occurs, `shape` comes from the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` interface.

In other words, ArcGIS is providing sDNA with data which somehow doesn't have a shape at all. Is it possible the input shapefile/gdb is somehow corrupted?

I haven't tried sDNA on ArcGIS 10.5 yet however the relevant parts of the interface look unchanged, and like you said it was working earlier.

Comment: I really hope not! How would I know if the shapefile/gdb is corrupted?

Comment: Hard to say, though I have had it happen on occasion with gdbs. In this case (null geometry) see if you can use this tool to detect/fix it: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm  The other way to detect corruption is just trying to recreate the data that it's not working on as PolyGeo suggested.

Comment: Also see my comment on your question, when you try running on a shapefile is the *output* set to shapefile as well? if you have mixed inputs/outputs (gdb/shapefile) sDNA will use ArcGIS to load and save data; if you set everything to shapefile it will use pyshp instead so may give you a different (or no) error

Comment: The output type is set to "feature classes", that's the only option to choose from. I will look into the repair geometry tool and update.